# No main manifest attribute, in tempCodeRunnerFile.jar

Tags: java, kotlin, jar

I'm trying to run a simple Kotlin code in Visual Studio Code, using the Code Runner extension. The code doesn't execute, though, and I get the following error:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   println("Hello, World!")
}
```

> [Running] cd "c:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\" && kotlinc tempCodeRunnerFile.kt -include-runtime -d tempCodeRunnerFile.jar && java -jar tempCodeRunnerFile.jar
>   no main manifest attribute, in tempCodeRunnerFile.jar

I'm new to Kotlin (Java) and I couldn't find a solution to this. Is there some setup that I need to do before being able to run Kotlin code locally? (I'm using Kotlin version 1.3.40-release-123 (JRE 12.0.1+12))

Answer (score 3):

include this to set class name (HelloKt for example)

```
@file:JvmName("HelloKt")
```

ref https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/493